# Extend Content types in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm writing a media collection manager in Drupal 8. now i have a couple of different content type (for books, games, movies, ...). Now I want to create a feature in the web app to extend the content type with some user specific fields.

How can I create a way for usrs to create a content type that will extend a master content type (books, games, movies,...)?

Comment: There is no "master content type"/extend concept in the core.
There is a module for Drupal 7 to inherit bundles. Never tested it and it is Drupal 7 so ...

Answer (score 2):

- create a new content type (called for example 'user extra fields') and give the rights for users to edit the content and create new content

  - add an entity reference field in the new content type that will refer to your original content type
  - the user will then select on new content , the content he wants to extend

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about use [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)? I think this is great way to extend your content type, because Paragraphs are, in fact, "mini content types". Additional advantage is that you have other groups of permission for users who will "extend" content type ;)

There is a good use case: https://www.amazeelabs.com/en/blog/drupal-paragraphs